# Eclipse Sonar Plugin - exclude test sources from analysis

Tags: eclipse, maven, sonarqube

Is there a possibility in eclipse to exclude the test sources of a maven project from the sonar analysis when running a local analysis?

Test code uses a lot more hard coded values than production code. So there are plenty of warnings, which say a constant should be used instead. But always using constants is in many cases redundant in test sources. I don't want to remove the rule, because this is necessary for production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open improvement for sonar that would add the functionality I would like to have. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2760

**EDIT:**
As of Sonar 3.5 the mentioned improvement has been implemented and is available.

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore i would say test code should has the same quality as production code cause it tests the production code so if i would be logical i would say the test code must have a better quality than production code.

I'm not sure but based on the docs of sonar there is something which is called ["Quality profiles"](http://www.sonarsource.org/using-quality-profiles-in-sonar/) which should handle the case you have.

Comment: You are right, that test sources should be clean too. But if I am using lots of constants only once there will be dozens of constant declarations at the beginning of the class, which also doesn't seem very clean.

Comment: I haven't found a possibility to configure source directory exclusions in a quality profile.